# How to differentiate in Jinja loop?

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

This is the general get-up of my database, I've got an 'exercises' table containing all exercises I'd like available,
Then a 'routines' table which creates an instance of a routine
And finally a 'routines_exercise' table which links the two together allowing for the user to create their own routine.

I've got an SQL statement which works fine and gives the right fields I desire, I just don't know how to filter through this statement in a jinja statement allowing me to specify which exercise goes to which fitness routine.

Currently, all exercises (despite some belonging to different fitness routines) are put into the first routine.

```
# To show a preview of all the user's fitness routines, maximum 3 exercises to be shown in the preview
@bp.route('/', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def index():
    db = get_db()
    routine = db.execute("SELECT * FROM routine_exercise WHERE user_id = ?", (g.user['id'],))
    routine_exercise = db.execute("SELECT name, weight, sets, reps FROM exercise, routine WHERE exercise.id = routine.exercise_id AND user_id = ?", (g.user['id'],))
    if routine is None:
        return render_template("routine/index.html")
    return render_template("routine/index.html", routine=routine, routine_exercise=routine_exercise)
```

```
{% for n in routine %}     
        <h5>{{ n['routine_name'] }} ({{ n['created'] }})</h5>
            {% for e in routine_exercise %}
                # here I wanted to split the exercises into different routine categories.
                {% if n['routine_id'] == e['id'] %}
                    <li>{{ e['name'] }} {{ e['weight'] }}kg {{ e['sets'] }}x{{ e['reps'] }}</li>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}    
            {% if not n.last %}
                <br>
            {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

[image: 1]

```
CREATE TABLE routine (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    user_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    routine_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    exercise_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    weight REAL,
    sets INTEGER NOT NULL,
    reps INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (exercise_id) REFERENCES exercise (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (routine_id) REFERENCES routine_exercise (id)
);

CREATE TABLE routine_exercise (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    user_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    routine_name TEXT NOT NULL,
    created DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE,
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user (id)
);

CREATE TABLE exercise (
    id  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    exercise_name   TEXT NOT NULL,
    target  TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

I tried around different ways of the if statement, but none worked.

Answer (score 0):

As Patrick Yoder mentioned, understanding your database schema is difficult. Since I don't understand the meaning of the association table, I simplified the tables a bit and hope the following result suits your needs.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    created DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE,
    name TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS exercise (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    created DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE,
    name TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS routine (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    created DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE,
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    weight REAL,
    sets INTEGER NOT NULL,
    reps INTEGER NOT NULL,
    user_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    exercise_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (exercise_id) REFERENCES exercise (id)
);
```

With these prerequisites, it is possible to query all required data with a JOIN statement within a single database query. In addition, duplicate columns that occur across multiple tables are eliminated.

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    db = get_db()
    rows = db.execute("""
        SELECT 
            exercise.name AS exercise_name, 
            exercise.created AS exercise_created, 
            routine.name AS routine_name, 
            routine.weight AS routine_weight, 
            routine.sets AS routine_sets, 
            routine.reps AS routine_reps 
        FROM exercise
        INNER JOIN routine
        ON exercise.id = routine.exercise_id
        WHERE routine.user_id = ?
        ORDER BY exercise.id, routine.name;
        """, (g.user['id'],)
    )
    return render_template('index.html', rows=rows)
```

Then the rows can be grouped by a column so that the data is displayed as in the desired example.

```
{% for name, items in rows | groupby('exercise_name') -%}
<div>
    <h2>{{ name }} ({{ items[0].exercise_created }})</h2>
    <ul>
        {% for item in items -%}
        <li>{{ item.routine_name }} {{ item.routine_weight }}kg {{ item.routine_sets }}&times;{{ item.routine_reps }}</li>
        {% endfor -%}
    </ul>
</div>
{% else -%}
<p>No routines found</p>
{% endfor -%}
```